# Split an array of integers into 3 number blocks with equal sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, sum

Don't know if I phrased it good, but I'll try to explain it further here:

So, I have an array of numbers, let's say `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 14` and I need to write an algorithm to split up the array into 3 number sized array with equal sums, which in this case would be:

`{14,2,4} {11,6,3} {10,1,9} {5,7,8}` - i think i got it.

So, what I have now in my head is:

Checking every possible sum of the integers, and putting three indexes used and the sum into a structure.

Then, with an array of structures, I would sort them by sum and would search for `N/3` number of sums, and if found, I print out the numbers according to their indexes.

The algorithm includes running through all numbers a lot of times, so it would be very slow. Can anyone suggest a better algorithm? If someone would like to give pieces of code, I can program in `C` and i have started learning `Java`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say if you're always going to start with 12 numbers.

You have the following array of numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 14

1. The count of the array of numbers must be divisible by 3.  If not, there is no solution.
2. Sum the array of numbers.  In this case, the sum is 80.
3. We have 12 numbers, so we have 4 groups of 3.  Divide the sum by the number of groups, which is 80 / 4, or 20.  If this division doesn't yield an integer, there is no solution.
4. Go through the array of numbers, three numbers at a time, **once**, and keep the triplets that sum to 20.  You can use a 12 bit binary integer, starting at zero and incrementing by 1, to select the triplets.  When the binary integer has 3 one bits, use the location of those bits as an index to your array of numbers.
5. Check to see if the group number of triplets exists and uses all of the numbers in the array.  If so, you have your solution.  If not, there is no solution.

Edited to add: It turns out that there are 4 solutions for the array of numbers given in the question:

```
(2,4,14); (3,6,11); (1,9,10); (5,7,8)
(2,4,14); (1,8,11); (3,7,10); (5,6,9)
(1,5,14); (3,6,11); (2,8,10); (4,7,9)
(1,5,14); (2,7,11); (4,6,10); (3,8,9)
```

I wrote the code just to see how long it would take to produce a solution.  It ran in less than a second.

Comment: Ye, there's N numbers, not always 12. E: After reading the whole post I realised myself how stupid I am for missing the point that we know the sum we need... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a hard problem. A bit difficult to write code for it, and it might take a long time to solve if you have lots of numbers.

First you check whether a solution can be possible. You have 12 numbers (if it was 11 or 13 you couldn't put them in groups of 3), so you want four groups of 3. The sum is 80, that's also good because you now need four groups of three numbers adding up to 20 each; if the sum was 79 or 78 that wouldn't work.

Sort the numbers in descending order. The biggest number must be in some group, so start with that: 14. 14 can be combined with 5,1 or 4,2. You check both possibilities.

The next biggest number must be in some group, so we take 11. Which could be combined with 8,1 or 7,2 or 6,3 or 5,4. If the first group was (14,5,1) then the second can be (11,7,2) or (11,6,3). If the first group was (14,4,2) then the second can be (11,8,1) or (11,6,3). So your choices don't grow too much.

So you can write a recursive function where you add one more group each time; each group that you add contains the largest remaining number, plus two numbers so the sum adds up to 20; you have to remove the numbers that you already picked. That's the rough idea.

Comment: Another user has already posted an easy solution, but yours seems more... Interesting. I will try it out on my free time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(rough sketch) Dynamic programming approach:

Have an array of 3 ints. Have a way for ints to be marked as used. Add the first unmarked number to the array and marked it as used. Add the next unmarked number and see if the sum is still below the target sum (you know how to get it). Try another number otherwise. Find out what number is missing and look for it (make sure its unmarked). Let's say you found it. You will have your triplet (you have store it somewhere, that's the memoization part that I will not cover to make it simple). Look for another triplet.

After every number is added to the triplet, look for the next one recursively so you can go back and try another combination if this one didn't work. How it works is that at some point you might reach the end of the array without building the triplet. Then, you have to return recursive call to try other number over there.

You are done only if you were able to mark all numbers.

There's definitely room for improvement here but if you understand what's dynamic programming about, you should get it.